# BufferGeometry and LineBasicMaterial: segments thickness

Tags: javascript, three.js, buffer-geometry

So I'm using a `THREE.BufferGeometry` and I'm able to control quite nicely the color of individual segment of the Line through the `color` attribute.

```
geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
});
geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(points, 3));
geometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(colors, 3));

scene.add(new THREE.Line(geometry, material, THREE.LinePieces));
```

Is there any way that I could add a custom attribute and bind it with `LineBasicMaterial.linewidth` so I could change thickness of individual segments of the line?

Comment: A custom line width on each segment is not supported. You will have to create separate lines for each line width desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shader to build lines and control thickness of each segment. Check this article https://processing.org/tutorials/pshader/ (chapter 10. Point and line shaders)